# Doctrine ODM Mongo DB Hydrator

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to handle hydrator of doctrine for avoiding this issue:

> The \"MongoDBODMProxies\__CG__\Foo\MyBundle\Document\MyDocument\" document with identifier \"53aae4fe8b589793538b456c\" could not be found."

I tried to use `orphanRemoval=true` on my ReferenceOne but it still doesn't work.

Here is my unidirectional structure to avoid complex/redondent data:

> DocB ==> $fieldDocA ==> ReferenceOne(targetDocument="DocA") ==> DocA

When I delete DocA, I want that Symfony delete automatically all documents where DocB contains `$fieldDocA === DocA` but I found nothing to do it properly on internet.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question resembles a [feature request we rejected](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/709) due to already existing solutions:

- [use lifecycle callbacks](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/709#issuecomment-44209765)
- use [reference integrity Doctrine extension](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/reference_integrity.md)